# Running custom code before launching app macOS

Tags: c, execvp

I'm having trouble running some C code before launching an app from Spotlight or the Applications folder. I figured I should just be able to create an executable with my code where after all the computations are done I make a `execvp()` call to run the original app's executable, which will then replace the current process.

I compiled the .c file and gave it the original app's executable name (in my case *clion*) and then executed it from Terminal.. great, it works!.. Until I tried to open the app bundle from spotlight (or Finder)

For some reason the `execvp()` call fails and the original program continues, but my custom executable is indeed called by spotlight! Not even making a child process with `fork()` will work, neither a `system()` call. What could be the problem here?

Contents folder of CLion: *clion* is my executable, *clion-real* is the original executable

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 marc  admin    8700 22 Mai 10:35 clion
-rw-r--r--  1 marc  admin     550 22 Mai 10:35 clion-fake.c
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 marc  admin  128353 21 Mai 12:56 clion-real
```

clion-fake.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    system("say 'called'");
    char* args[] = {"./clion-real", NULL};
    int status = execvp(args[0], args);
    system("say 'failed'");
    return 0;
}
```

When calling `./clion` from terminal it works as intended, the system says *called* and the app opens, but when opening the .app from Spotlight it says both *called* and *failed*, which means that the `execvp()` call failed.

Comment: Check the values of `status` and `errno` after the `execvp` call.

Comment: status is -1, errno is 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errno 2 is `ENOENT`, aka "no such file or directory".

You need to make sure that the current working directoy for the execution of your `clion` binary is actually set to the directory where your binaries live in, otherwise relative paths like `./clion-real` won't work.